# Bind swift property's value to viewModel's property

Tags: swift, mvvm, binding, reactive-cocoa

I know, the question can be stupid, sorry for that.

**Situation:**

UIViewController with property
`var selectedItem: (item: ItemEntity, index: Int)?`

```
struct ItemEntity {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
```

And viewModel with property
`var itemVM = MutableProperty<String>("")`

**Question:**
If i want to bind textField.text value changing i just use

```
viewModel.name <~ nameField.rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer()
```

But how i can bind changing of `id` property of `item` to viewModel's `itemVM`?
( I've tried something like

```
  viewModel.itemVC <~ SignalProducer(value: selectedItem?.item.id ?? "")
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, is there a reason why you are using the ObjectiveC API of RAC (`rac_textSignal()`)?

Of course, thats still valid (especially, if you also have Objective C code in your app).

However, the [5.0.0 Release of Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/releases/tag/5.0.0) has introduced UI-Bindings to the Swift API which allows you to change from

```
viewModel.name <~ nameField.rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer()
```

to

```
viewModel.name <~ nameField.reactive.continuousTextValues
```

which is now properly typed as `Signal<String?, NoError>`

If you don't have any ObjC code in your App, you don't need to import the whole ObjC API of Reactive Cocoa anymore with 5.0.0

**To your actual question:**

What you did with `SignalProducer(value: selectedItem?.item.id ?? "")` was to create a `SignalProducer`, that immediately sends the value given in the parameter, and then completes. Thats why you could not observe any changes this way.

If you want to observe the changes over time, I would first change `selectedItem` to a `MutableProperty`:

```
typealias SelectedItem = (item: ItemEntity, index: Int)
let selectedItem = MutableProperty<SelectedItem?>(nil)
```

Now, you can set the `selectedItem` like this:

```
let item1 = ItemEntity(id: "1", name: "One")
selectedItem.value = (item: item1, index: 0)
```

Assuming, `viewModel.itemVC` is of Type `MutableProperty<String>`, you can now bind the selectedItem like this:

```
viewModel.itemVC <~ selectedItem.map { $0?.item.id ?? "" }
```

Btw, you could think about moving the `selectedItem` to the viewModel as well.